# Natural Deduction First Order Logic $∃y∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(y))↔∀x∃y(P(x) ∨ Q(y))$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I'm working on some of my logic exercises for my end term exam in Predicate Logic. One of these exercises is "Show with natural deduction that $\vdash ∃y∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(y))↔∀x∃y(P(x) ∨ Q(y))$"

I'm getting the part that shows you can do $∃y∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(y)) \vdash ∀x∃y(P(x) ∨ Q(y))$. It's the other way around I'm not able to do. I'm getting stuck introducing the Universal Quantifier whilst having them as a free variable.

[Where I'm getting stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M70Ts.jpg)

I know this isn't correct/possible, but I cannot figure out how it should be done...

Is there anyone who is able to solve it? Or is it simply not possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These are not equivalent.

Comment: You are correct, there was a typo, now it should be better :)

Comment: From left to right it is true. from right to left it is false.

Comment: So you are telling me that using natural deduction I cannot show |- ∃y∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(y))↔∀x∃y(P(x) ∨ Q(y)) ?

Comment: @JesseGrootjen If I may suggest, don't think of things in terms of "prove in natural deduction".  Just start with a proof, any proof, informal is fine.  Then convert that proof to natural deduction.  If you can't make a proof in any context, how do you expect to make a proof specific to natural deduction?

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*

It must be derivable, due to the fact that it is *valid* (in classical logic).

We may check it with two equivalences :

> $\exists x \ (\alpha \lor \beta(x)) \equiv (\alpha \lor \exists x \beta(x))$, if $x$ is not *free* in $\alpha$

and (this one holds only in classical logic) :

> $\forall x \ (\alpha \lor \beta(x)) \equiv (\alpha \lor \forall x \beta(x))$, if $x$ is not *free* in $\alpha$.

Thus, starting from :

> $∃y∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(y))$

we can get, by the second equivalence above : $∃y(∀xP(x) ∨ Q(y))$ and then, using the first one we get the equivalent :

> $(∀xP(x) ∨ ∃yQ(y))$.

Now we re-apply the second equivalence to get :

> $∀x(P(x) ∨ ∃yQ(y))$

and finally :

> $∀x∃y (P(x) ∨ Q(y))$.

Comment: I don't think my proof uses non-intuitionist logic?

Comment: @KennyLau Your post is pure intuitionistic logic, but it only goes in 1 direction.  The other direction is the hard one, it appears to be non constructive.